# Mongoose ensureIndex error when start

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

```js
var eventSchema = new Schema({
title : {
    type:String,
    required : true,
    index: true
}});
```

If index value is true it will make my program send error

> Mongoose: events.ensureIndex({ title: 1 }) { background: true }

I have no idea what happened. Please explain. I'm new to node.js and Mongoose.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var animalSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  tags: { type: [String], index: true } // field level
});

animalSchema.index({ name: 1, type: -1 }); // schema level
```

check this , its useful to you

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html